# How to implement a hybrid quick sort algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have been trying to create a hybrid quick sort algorithm, with the first element used as a pivot, where when the partition size is below a 100 an insertion sort is used to finish. I then have to compare the number of comparisons and number of swaps performed, to a standard quick sort algorithm. The sorting for my code seems to work, but somehow the number of comparisons and swaps is unchanged when the partition size is altered. Not sure where exactly the problem in my code is.

```
public class QuickSort100 {

    int comparisonCount = 0;
    int swapCount = 0;

    public void quicksort(int [] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex ) {

        if ((lowIndex - highIndex) >= 100){
            int index = partition(array, lowIndex, highIndex);
            if (lowIndex < index -1){
                quicksort(array, lowIndex, index-1);
            }
            if (index < highIndex){
                quicksort(array, index, highIndex);
            }
        }
        else {
            insertionSort(array);
        }
    }

    public int [] insertionSort (int[] array) {
        int i, j, key, temp;
        for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            key = array[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && key < array[j]) {
                comparisonCount++;
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
                j--;
                swapCount++;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }


    public int partition(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex){

        int pivot = array[lowIndex];

        int i = lowIndex + 1 ;

        for (int j = (lowIndex +1); j < highIndex; j++){
            comparisonCount++;
         
            if(array[j] < pivot){
                swap(array,i,j);
                swapCount++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        swap(array, lowIndex, i-1);
        swapCount++;
        return i;
    }


    public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j]= temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: *"when the partition size is altered"*: what does that mean? In QuickSort the partition size changes continually...

Comment: So once the partition left or right of the pivot is a 100 or below, we use an insertion sort to sort it.

Comment: Yes, but that part I understood from the code. What do you mean with *"when the partition size is altered"*?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean that if I make the partition size 50 or below, it outputs the number of comparisons the same as for a 100 or below, which seems wrong

Comment: `if ((lowIndex - highIndex) >= 100)` don't you mean `if ((highIndex - lowIndex) >= 100)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the insertion sort to use lowIndex and highIndex, not the entire array.